# Uploading image to Multer on Node JS server from Xamarin C# app

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, xamarin, multer

I'm trying to upload an image to a Node JS from a PCL Xamarin forms library. I've tried using the Multer Node JS library to pick up the the POST request. The request is received, however the photo is not saved. The file is always 'undefined'.

**Node JS code:**

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './photouploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        console.log(file.fieldname);
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image');

exports.post = function (req, res) {
    console.log("Photo Api Hit");
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        console.log(req.file);
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(err);
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        console.log("File has been received");
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

**C#/Xamarin Code**

```
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Vigour.Controllers
{
    class MediaController
    {
        public static void upload(MediaFile mediaFile)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamContent scontent = new StreamContent(mediaFile.GetStream());
                scontent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                { 
                    FileName = "newimage",
                    Name = "image"
                };
                scontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.API_ROOT_URL);
                var result = client.PostAsync("api/photo", scontent).Result;
                Debug.WriteLine(result.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Does anyone know how the request should be formed in my C# code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using this method was effective for a PCL

The MediaFile is an object from the Xamarin.Plugins.Media Library

```
 public static void upload(MediaFile mediaFile)
 {
            try
            {
                StreamContent scontent = new StreamContent(mediaFile.GetStream());
                scontent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    FileName = "newimage",
                    Name = "image"
                };
                scontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

                var client = new HttpClient();
                var multi = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                multi.Add(scontent);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.API_ROOT_URL);
                var result = client.PostAsync("api/photo", multi).Result;
                Debug.WriteLine(result.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
  }
```

I used node js (hosted on azure) to receive the request.

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        console.log(file.fieldname);
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image');

exports.post = function (req, res) {
    console.log("Photo Api Hit");
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        console.log(req.file);
        if (err) {
            console.log("Photo API ERROR: "+err);
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

Comment: Took me a week to find your answer, which worked. I don't have anything super-enlightening to say about it. If you're going to post from C# to multer, you need to use form-data, and you need to use StreamContent. Nothing else worked.